# Get Text from React Textfield Select

Tags: reactjs

How do I get the current text from a Material UI TextField Select Component? I'm storing the id in the state:

```
const [MunicipioId, setMunicipioId] = useState(0);
const handleChangeMunicipioSeleccionado = (e) => {
    setMunicipioId(e.target.value);
    setBarrioId(0);
    traerBarriosPorMunicipio(e.target.value);
}
```

And the component is the following:

```
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
                <TextField
                variant = "outlined"
                onChange={handleChangeMunicipioSeleccionado}
                value={MunicipioId}
                label="Municipio"
                fullWidth
                select
                >
                {municipios.length > 0 ? municipios.map((municipio)=>(
                    <MenuItem key={municipio.MunicipioId} value={municipio.MunicipioId}>{municipio.MunicipioNombre}</MenuItem>
                )): <MenuItem disabled>No se encontraron municipios</MenuItem>}
                </TextField>
            </Grid>
```

I need to get the text from it, in this case {municipio.MunicipioNombre} from each item selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the by giving the value attribute the data value in your case

```
value={municipio.MunicipioId}
```

here is a codepen link in which I formatted your code. I used data from the material UI official site
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-driscoll-3rlhs?file=/src/App.js:0-1057